# Adware vs. Cloudfare

Tags: cookies

How can I find out if a website is injecting adware when the "checking your browser-wait 5 seconds" interstitial page is shown? Exactly what goes on in the background during this "test"? I know a cookie is placed on my PC because if I clear my history after gaining access to the site, the 5 second page pops up again if I click on anything else on the page.

Is there a way to decode the cookie into plain English?

Comment: why do you think there is adware involved?

Comment: the cookie will plainly tell you that it is from cloudflare

Comment: How would you find out if a website is injecting adware (where?) at any other point in time? What makes you think this intermediate page is special?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can check by checking what ads you see? But it is unlikely you would get adware this way.

What is actually happening is cloudflare is verifying you are not a bot (program designed to spam, DOS or otherwise attack the site). Once the verification is done, they give you a cookie that is a proof you are not a bot. If you delete the cookie, cloudflare needs to verify again.

More info [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/what-is-the-website-checking-about-my-browser-to-protect-the-website-from-a-ddos).