# Checking IP's reputation on CloudFlare and Google

Tags: ddos, botnet, cloudflare

Google and CloudFlare have recently indicated that my home IP address is contributing to a DDoS or spam network.

I am frequently being checked ([What is the website checking about my browser to protect the website from a DDoS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/what-is-the-website-checking-about-my-browser-to-protect-the-website-from-a-ddos)) and some websites are blocked entirely.

Do Google or CloudFlare allow me to view the data implicating my IP? It might be helpful to me to find the source.

https://radar.cloudflare.com/ does not appear to show this.

Comment: This is a question for those services. For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=why+am+I+blacklisted+cloudflare